# R levels function returning NULL by calling dataset column

Tags: r, null

I'm trying to find levels of a specific column in a dataset.

Suppose I have a dataset as below:

```
    df
    apple    orange
      1        3
      2        4
      4        7
      3        1
      2        4
      .        3
      1        2
```

In my original dataset, column apple is structured as of the following displayed in console:

```
  <chr>          
   1 7              
   2 2              
   3 4              
   4 1              
   5 1              
   6 6              
   7 5              
   8 2              
   9 4              
   10 2              
   # ... with 17,273 more rows
```

I made sure that each column is converted to factor and rid of missings by the following function:

```
    convert_missing <- function(x){

       column <- as.character(x)
       column[is.na(column)] <- "Missing_"
       column <- as.factor(column)
       column <- factor(column, levels(column)[order(as.numeric(levels(column)))])
       return(column)
    }
```

then if I pass a column in df to convert_missing and to extract levels of the column I'm not sure why I always receive NULL as the outcome, such as:

```
  df_vars <- list()
  df["apple"] <-lapply(df["apple"],convert_missing)
  df_vars[["DV_Levels"]] <- levels(df[, "apple"]) #this returns NULL
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. On my system, `levels(df[,"apple"])` returns `"1" "2" "3" "4" "."` (as it should).

Comment: Hi @t2evans, for my original dataset the column is formatted as <chr> such  as <chr>          
 7              
 2              
 4              
 1              
 1              
 6              
 5              
 2              
 4              
 2              
# ... with 17,273 more rows